# Orchard CMS Static Resources from Modules return 404

Tags: iis, orchardcms

I have deployed Orchard via Web PI to IIS7. The problem I am having is that all the static content (css/js) that are requested from /Modules/ directory are not being served by the server and return 404.

At the same time static content from Core loads fine.

What is the general strategy to troubleshoot this problem?

The url of Orchard test deployment is [cms.radacode.com](http://cms.radacode.com)

P.S. A fresh WebPI installation of Orchard is affected by the same problem. Most likely it has something to do with permissions on IIS, but it is not clear why only /Modules/ folder is being blocked for content retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in folders like Scripts, Content, etc. there is a web.config that enables access to static content.  Do you have that web.config in the folder where you are trying to access static files from?

Here is an example from the Blogs module: [Web.config](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Blogs/Content/Web.config)

Comment: The URL Seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, messed around with file permissions etc before finding the solution.

I had installed Orchard 1.6.1 on my Win8 dev pc, and all worked fine.
Copied to my Windows Server 2008 hosting server, and the first I noticed was the Admin -> Widgets section was laid out incorrectly on the hosting server version.

After some investigation, found that css files from the /Modules/Orchard.Widgets/Styles/ were giving a 404.

I finally tracked down the cause of my problem to be UrlScan blocking access to folders with . in them!

Changed UrlScan.ini 
from 
AllowDotInPath=0
to
AllowDotInPath=1
and all working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by switching the website to ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated mode (instead of standard Classic mode)..

Comment: Checked it first place - the pool is in Integrated mode =(

Comment: The other thing that might cause you some problems is that Orchard must run in at least medium trust, and I think that newer versions (maybe even 1.6) will require full trust and won't be able to run even in medium trust mode.. And if you're on shared hosting, that will be tough to get.. There is also a not enough memory issue that causes your session to constantly reset that you might bump into if you're using shared hosting. If you do run into it, you can resolve it to manually set machine key.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan. I've read about memory. Will check the trust though. I am running on an own server in datacenter, so I have a full control over the environment.

Comment: OK, than I might just be looking at things from different perspective. Are the modules that are throwing exceptions standard modules or your own? If they are your own, do you have a separate web.config in each directory that has a static resource (you should)? Are there a proper permissions set on Modules directory?

Comment: Changing to Integrated worked for me! Shared hosting, but it has Full Trust (Croatian Quality ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, more information:

- http : //MySite/Themes/**TheThemeMachine**/Styles/Site.css OK for everyone
- Access to http : //MySite/Themes/**MyTheme**/Styles/site.css works only for logged in user (admin) and is blocked for anonymous users
- web.config are the same in both theme folders
- Windows server 2012
- Orchard 1.6.1.0 (compiled from sources)
- On the development computer (using Development Server) everything is OK, so it is difficult to trace the problem.

As a workaround changed the site.css on TheThemeMachine, but still looking for a proper fix.